# Running psql TRUNCATE command from JENKINS

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, psql

Im trying to execute a psql command as below from jenkins (freestyle or pipeline).

But it stays forever with the wheel spinning and never ends with any error.
The same command executes fine on the node where job is restricted.

```
psql --host=database --dbname=database_name --port=5444 --username=user -c "TRUNCATE TABLE table_name"
```

Any advise ?

Comment: Maybe your DDL is simply blocked by another query/process.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda , no that is not the case. It runs from node console every time no problems